# Estimating the error of $\sin x \approx x-\frac {x^3}{6}$ for $|x|\le \frac 12$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, taylor-expansion

> Estimate the error of $\sin x \approx x-\frac {x^3}{6}$ for $|x|\le \frac 12$

It seems too easy so I just want to make sure:

Since $f(x)-p(x)\le R(x)$ and $R_5(x)=\cos (c) \frac {x^5} {5!}$

So we just need to solve: $|\cos (c) \frac {x^5} {5!}|\le|1\cdot (\frac 1 2)^5\frac 1 {5!}|\approx 0.00026$ which is the estimation of the error (?)

Comment: @Dr.MV how is it not zero since $\sin 0 =0$?

Comment: Your approach is correct.  It is that simple.